# Magento 1.9 cron scheduler change timezone

Tags: magento-1.9, cron, magento-cron

i'm a magento newbie. I wrote a cron job code in my custom module's observer file and ran cron job from terminal. Scheduled jobs are entered into cron_schedule table. But the scheduled time is in UTC. Where should I change it to set scheduled time in Asia/Kolkata timezone.

[image]

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the timeline settings within magento configs and on the server where it is being hosted. Make sure they all match.